# Editing keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard-layout

In `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` keyboard layout files,
how can I edit the 102nd key, that is usually next to left shift? What is the code for it? I tried AB00, but that does not work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The 102nd key (usually found on most European keyboards) has the code `<LSGT>`. For standard PC102/105 keyboards  it is initially set in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pc`.